# Can WPF App run in Win 8.1 Kiosk Mode

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8.1

very simple question, which I'm struggling to find an answer. Can a WPF app run in Windows 8.1 Kiosk mode?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hyperyash/archive/2013/10/25/enable-kiosk-mode-in-windows-8-1.aspx): "... You need to keep in mind that this application needs to be a modern application and cannot be a desktop application ...".

Comment: @Clemens, thanks for the response. As mentioned in previous post, I'm looking at using the System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser control, because the WebView control is creating a lot of problems, where as the System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser control isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple answer: No.

Windows imersive mode uses its own platform: WinRT.

Although, its very similar to WPF and you can reuse most of your C# and XAML code, but you'll definitely need to correct a lot of things since WinRT uses a lot of Async methods.

Comment: Thanks! Not the answer I was looking for.... to be honest! I specifically want to make use of the System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser control in WPF, because the WebView in WinRT is creating a lot of problems.

Comment: Yes indeed. Also, the WinRT is pretty restrictive when it comes to IO and networking, might get anyone pretty mad, I know the feel.